# Write a spark DataFrame to a table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand the spark DataFrame API method called saveAsTable.

I have following question

- If I simply write a dataframe using saveAsTable API
  `df7.write.saveAsTable("t1")`, (assuming t1 did not exist earlier), will the newly created table be a hive table which can be read outside spark using Hive QL ?
- Does spark also create some non-hive table (which are created using saveAsTable API but can not be read outside spark using HiveQL)?
- How can check if a table is Hive Table or Non-Hive table ?

(I am new to big data processing, so pardon me if question is not phrased properly)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Newly created table will be hive table and can be queried from `Hive CLI`(Only if the DataFrame is created from single input `HDFS` path i.e. from non-partitioned single input `HDFS` path).

Below is the documentation comment in `DataFrameWriter.scala` class. [Documentation link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala)

> When the DataFrame is created from a non-partitioned
> `HadoopFsRelation` with a single input path, and the data source
> provider can be mapped to an existing Hive builtin SerDe (i.e. ORC and
> Parquet), the table is persisted in a Hive compatible format, which
> means other systems like Hive will be able to read this table.
> Otherwise, the table is persisted in a Spark SQL specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do. You table can be partitioned by a column, but can not use bucketing (its a problem between spark and hive).